# SiP domain demo (android)

Tags: android, sip, demo

I'm using demo http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/index.html and trying to make a call via SiP, I have 2 android devices with wi-fi connection, but here's my problem - what is SiP domain? I've read about this, but I didn't understand - should I run SiP server somewhere or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run Asterisk on a Linux server and have both devices register to it. Then you will be able to call. You should also be able to call directly if you specify the username and the other phones IP address as the domain, but you'll have to modify the demo.